# Move multiple files by the date in file name into date named folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have around 100,000 files with names like:

- `completedCourses_2017-10-08 11 18-05-02.txt`
  or
- `emptyCoursesResults_2017-10-08 11 13-21-59.txt`

All these files are in one directory, and I want to "split" it by date into directories, e.g. all files with date `2017-10-08` going into directory with name `2017-10-08`, files with date `2018-01-02` going into directory with name `2018-01-02` - no matter what is on start of name and on end.

Is it possible using a Windows solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop and set the `"USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=_ "` like that to parse out and get the date string from the file name to reuse in subsequent commands accordingly for the operations you need.

You will then use a mixture of commands such as `DIR`, `MD`, `XCOPY`, and `DEL` to perform the file operations to get those moved over to the new date string folder.

**Note:** *Be sure to set the `Src=` variable value to be the folder where these files exist, and be sure to set the `Dest=` variable value to be the folder where the files will be moved and the `yyyy-mm-dd` folder will be created for those files to reside once moved*.

```
@ECHO ON

SET "Src=C:\Folder\Source"
SET "Dest=C:\Folder\Destination"

FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=_ " %%A IN (`DIR /B "%Src%\*.txt"`) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%%~A" MD "%%~A"
    XCOPY /F /Y "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt" "%Dest%\%%~A\" && DEL /Q /F "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt"
    )

EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- **`FOR /?`**

  > ```
  >     delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
  >                       default delimiter set of space and tab.
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  >     usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
  >                       where a back quoted string is executed as a
  >                       command and a single quoted string is a
  >                       literal string command and allows the use of
  >                       double quotes to quote file names in
  >                       file-set.
  > ```
- [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [DEL](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [DIR](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

Comment: @Paul .... Please note that this solution requires the file names to be standard as per your example too so `emptyCoursesResults_2017-10-08 11 13-21-59.txt` means the file name will always have the `YYYY-MM-DD` portion of the file name **come after the first underbar i.e. "`_`"** and also "**after the date string there will always be a space**". This logic was tested with those two things always being true for these files in the same one folder so `"_YYYY-MM-DD "`.

Comment: @Paul ... Lastly and furthermore, I think you could add `IF EXIST "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt"` to the front of the `XCOPY /F /Y "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt" "%Dest%\%%~A\" && DEL /Q /F "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt"` line to take care of potentially false positive type errors per the way the logic iterates and it using the wild cards so if needed 8th link down in the script would be `IF EXIST "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt" XCOPY /F /Y "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt" "%Dest%\%%~A\" && DEL /Q /F "%Src%\*%%~A*.txt"` like that instead.

Comment: Awesome, very informative answers sir. Not exactly a Windows guy, but I do test some of the scripts and examples you post, which most are extremely useful for repetitive tasks. Kudos! 